# Definition of Q gorenstein variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

I have a question about the definition of Q-Gorenstein variety.

I saw a definition of Q-Gorenstein variety：for a normal variety $X$, it's Q-Gorenstein if the canonical divisor is Q Cartier. I wonder how to use this definition (about canonical divisor) to see the structure ring is Q-Gorenstein. Through some duality?

Maybe there's no such thing like $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein ring? Basically, I want to know from canonical divisor is $\mathbb Q$ Cartier, what can we say about the structure ring R. Here I mean locally X=Spec(R).

Comment: The structure ring is $\Bbb{Q}$-Gorenstein, not Gorenstein.

Comment: @abx Thanks,edited it

Comment: What is your definition of $\Bbb{Q}$-Gorenstein? For me, it is the property that you quote.

Comment: @abx. On a normal variety, I want to ask if the canonical divisor is $Q$-Cartier, how to show that on on affine piece X=Spec(R), the ring R is $Q$-Gorenstein.

Comment: Again: what is, for you, the meaning of "the ring R is Q-Gorenstein"? What definition do you have in mind?

Comment: @abx, Sorry for the impreciseness. I think there's a standard definition of Gorenstein ring. Maybe no definition of Q-Gorenstein ring? Basically, I want to know from the Q-Cartier property of canonical divisor, what can we say about the structure ring?

Comment: I do not know of any other definition of $\Bbb{Q}$-Gorenstein. For Gorenstein it is equivalent to finite injective dimension, as you will find in any textbook in commutative algebra.

Comment: @abx Thanks! I know what's Gorenstein ring. As I said, I don't know how it's related  to the Cartier property of canonical divisor.

Comment: See Hartshorne's *Residues and duality*, Ch. V, §9.

Comment: @abx Great, that's what I want!